# Python code in OSX Terminal not compiling right

Tags: python, macos

So I am trying to teach myself to program in Python while on spring break and I have run into a roadblock. I can get my code to compile in PyCharm, but I would really like to get it to compile correctly in Terminal because vim is my text-editor of choice. Does anyone have any idea of why my code may not be compiling correctly?

[Here is my code compiling correctly in PyCharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRcOm.png)

[Here is my code compiling incorrectly in Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDbUa.png)

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Looks to me like you're using Python3.5 in PyCharm, but Python2.X in the terminal.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that python isn't exactly compiling your code. It's being interpreted which is a different way to implement a programming language. A compiler translates source code into lower level code which is itself executable, while an interpreter is a program that parses and acts on behalf of "executed" source code. Check out [this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/24558/is-python-interpreted-or-compiled) if you find this hair splitting fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any recent OSX version comes with Python 2.7 as a standard. When you install Python 3.x, you have both versions on your system. The standard way of using `python -command-` in the terminal calls Python 2.7. You can call a command using `python3 -command-` instead to use Python 3.x. You could set an alias on `python3` in .bash_profile to call it instead when you use `python`.

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm not sure if there are any functions in OSX that use Python 2.7 which would be disturbed by making the alias switch in .bash_profile.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much, the python3 command did the trick. I think it may be safer just to not make an alias in .bash_profile, mainly because I am not very comfortable in making new environmental variables and the like (if that is what an alias is considered).

Answer (score 0):

You have configured PyCharm to use an installed Python 3, but at the terminal you appear to be using Python 2. There is a difference in how the two versions output the results of `print`. Try modifying your terminal session to direct your path to use the installed Python 3 instead of the installed Python 2.

Comment: When you say to direct my path to use Python 3, are you talking about placing that new path in the .bash_profile? Because I did that, but am still not getting it to interpret my input correctly. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: "When you say to direct my path to use Python 3, are you talking about placing that new path in the .bash_profile? Because I did that, "  What does the command `python --version` print?  If it prints a version number beginning with "2", then you *didn't* successfully direct your path to use Python 3.

Comment: python --version returns 2.7.11, which is not good. I am still pretty new when it comes to a lot in terminal, but thank you very much for your help. I am going to try to get this figured out.